# Rails: instance variable on site is not being updated on div reload via ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

My goal is to use coffeescript to read the value from a `number_field` in the view, send the value to the controller and then send the number value from the controller back to the view.

In the coffeescript file I use `console.log(qty)` as a check to see, if coffeescript is able to read the `number_field` value. This check passes.

In the controller I use `puts "received #{@n}"` and `puts "not received"` as checks. On page load the `else` portion should execute, since the `.change` event has not yet triggered. When the number field is changes the `if` portion should execute. This test passes correctly. When the number field is changed the correct value for `@n` is printed to the rails console. This means that the `params[:quantity]` is received by the controller action.

The last step would be for `$('#insert-here').load(location.href+" #insert-here")` to reload the `#insert-here` `div` on the page. To check this I added `<%= Time.now %>` in the view to see that the timestamp changes. This test passes as well, but `<h1><%= @n %></h1>` in the view continues to show the number `1`. It does not update. How can I fix this?

View

```
<%= oi.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: 'form-control', id: 'quantity-select', min: 1 %>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="insert-here"><h1><%= @n %></h1><h2><%= Time.now %></h2></div>
```

Coffeescript

```
ready = ->
  $('#quantity-select').change ->
    qty = document.getElementById('quantity-select').value
    $.ajax
      complete: (request) ->
      data: { quantity: qty }
      console.log(qty)
      $('#insert-here').load(location.href+" #insert-here")
    return
  return
$(document).ready(ready)
```

Controller

```
 def show
   if params[:quantity].present?
     @n = params[:quantity]
     puts "received #{@n}"
   else
     @n = 1
     puts "not received"
   end  
end
```

Comment: first change it to `$('#quantity-select').change ->` if you have id why do you need other attributes

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will be sure to update that. Any tips on why the code is currently not returning the correct quantity in the view?